# UIViewController - UIModalPresentationCurrentContext not rotating presentingViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I used to present a `UIViewController` from another `UIViewController` with presentation style `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext`. But it wont allow me to rotate the `presentingviewcontroller` (The `UIViewController` that presented new `UIViewController` )

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
NewViewController *newViewController = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" Bundle: nil];
[self presentViewController:newViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When I rotate the device it will rotate the `newViewController` and `statusbar` but not `presentingViewController`

PS: Here `presentingViewController` is `self`.

[image]

Comment: Is presentingViewController child of any other controller? Maybe you forgot to add it as a child and it is not getting any events.

Comment: no it is rootViewController.

Comment: In other presentation styles it works fine but not in `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext`.

Comment: Please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17839785/591951

Comment: i also facing same issue ....have you got the answer?

Comment: Not through `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` . I changed it to `UIModelPresentationFormSheet` and change its superview size that solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` instead of `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext`

Try this

`self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModelPresentationFormSheet;
NewViewController *newViewController = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" Bundle: nil];
[self presentViewController:newViewController animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: UIModalPresentationFormSheet is not available in iPhone